# Which is the difference between these two sets?

Tags: general-topology, notation, manifolds, mathematical-physics

I am studying [The large scale structure of space-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Large_Scale_Structure_of_Space-Time) by Hawking and Ellis. They use the sets $\partial A$ and $\dot{A}$; they seem to be both some kind of border of the set $A$, but they are different. Which is the difference between these two sets?

**EDIT** I thought it was a standard notation, so I did not included the definition:

$$\dot{A}=\bar{A}\cap\overline{(M-A)}$$

where $M$ is a manifold.

Why is this not the same as the boundary $\partial A$

Comment: I don't know that book personality, but they ought to have _defined_ these two notations at some point.

Comment: Typically, $\partial A$ denotes the [boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)). It may also denote the [boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary) of a manifold, which is different.

Comment: $\dot{A}$ may denote the [interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)) of $A$.

Comment: @Arthur see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition you added is the standard boundary of a set in a topological space. (In the context of general topology, $∂$ or $\operatorname{bd}$ is usually used). In the context of manifolds, $∂$ is used for the boundary of a manifold, which is different. For example if $A = M$, the topological boundary is always empty, but that is not the case for the manifold boundary. Also, if I'm not mistaken, the manifold boundary is the matter of the whole manifold rather than of a subset of the manifold.